# Align Word table

Tags: python, c#, vba, ms-word, win32com

Is there a way how to align a table itself, not it's contents?

I want this:

[image]

but **not** this

[image]

I tried the following (code is for Python, but that's almost the same for VBA of C#):

```
word_table = self._word_app.Selection.Tables(1)
    
word_table.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = client.constants.wdAlignParagraphCenter
word_table.Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = client.constants.wdAlignParagraphCenter

word_table.Select()
self._word_app.Selection.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = client.constants.wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

But it only aligns contents.
Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
word_table.Rows.Alignment = client.constants.wdAlignRowCenter
```